# MATLAB: Plot a function with vector-valued input

Tags: matlab

What is the easiest way to plot the graph of a function with vector-valued input? For example:

```
f = @(x) x(1)^2 + x(1)*x(2) + x(2)^3
```

Similarly, if `f` is a vector field, how can one use `quiver` to plot it if `f` has vector-valued input. For example:

```
f = @(x) [x(2)*cos(x(1)); x(1)*sin(x(1))]
```

Comment: It isn't clear what exactly your function is supposed to be.  Is $f(x)$ a function of three variables, i.e. $f(x) = x_1^2 + x_1 x_2 + x_2^3$?   If so, then you should write `f = @(x1,x2,x3)  x1.^2 + x1.*x2 + x2.^3`  Then pass in vectors for `x1`, `x2`. `x3`

Comment: If ``f``was written as ``f = @(x,y) x.^2 + x.*y + y.^3``, then I would have no problem plotting it. My question is if it is possible to plot ``f`` if it is defined as above. It is still a function ``R^2 -> R``. It's just that the input is a vector.

Comment: (I realize I mis-represented your function as a function of 3 variables).  But it still isn't clear what you mean by "the input is a vector".  The reference to x(1) and x(2) in the definition of $f$ suggests that x is already a vector.   Do you mean the input is an N x 2  array?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using (with modifications to your function)

```
fplot(@(x) sin(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that there is a function `arrayfun` that basically does what i want:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(linspace(-2,2));
Z = arrayfun(@(x,y) f([x;y]),X,Y);
mesh(X,Y,Z)
```

So `f`will be applied to each pair in `X`and `Y`.